# Augment a matrix in NumPy

Tags: matrix, numpy, concatenation

I start with a 2x4 matrix A

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

I also have another 1x4 matrix B

```
B = np.matrix([9, 10, 11, 12])
```

How do I concatenate A and B so that I get a 3x4 matrix C

```
C = [[9 10 11 12]
     [1 2 3 4]
     [5 6 7 8]]
```

Note that B is prepended before row 0 of matrix A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html

```
C = np.concatenate((B, A))
```

Answer (score 7):

The r_ command also works:

```
np.r_[C,B]
```

also works (and np.c_ is a variant on r_ for gluing columns)